# Iphone app for german app-store (localization)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xamarin.ios, app-store

i recently published an iphone app using monotouch to the market.
It's currently in the waiting for review status.

Today i found out that when clicking on the button "View in appstore", the following happens:

1. Itunes openes with the following message (Your app is in the US-Market, click to change your default ....)
2. "Your app is not available in the us market".

I'm irritated about this messages and unsure if i did anything wrong because i did not use the official localization. My localization is completely build in C# and does not use "lproj" files.

So i DO NOT have any +en.lproj or de.lproj folders in my app.bundle.

The binary details in Itunes-Connect says the the following: Localizations: ("en")

Does this mean my app will not be available in the german market if it gets approved, even though my default language in Itunes Connect is "german" and i have added all the app-details in german?

How does Itunes Connect decide in which markets the app is available?

The problem is that i don't want to publish a new binary and risk waiting another +5days, because the app should already be in the market (customers ...)

Just the be clear: The app does have english and german localization strings and will show the correct ones depending on the user-language -> but it's all written in C# ...

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with your localization.  When you setup a new app in the app store you can specify which markets it is available in.  Further, I don't think I would expect the app store url to work for an app that has not been reviewed yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does this mean my app will not be available in the german market if it gets approved, even though my default language in Itunes Connect is "german" and i have added all the app-details in german?
>   How does Itunes Connect decide in which markets the app is available?

Find under Manage Your Applications -> "YourAppName" -> Rights & Pricing -> "specific stores". You can change all territories in there.

As long you app is not reviewed yet -the app store link does not work.

Comment: That's reassuring to know, thanks. The whole distribution process was really insane so far, so i guess I am bit paranoiac at the moment :)